# Running PHP scripts on Synology from within Docker container

Tags: docker, synology, domoticz

Today I had to move my Domoticz/jadahl/Synology setup to one that runs in a Docker container. While this didn’t give any problems, I have one issue. Domoticz allows scripts to be executed when a switch is toggled. I have been running PHP scripts for years this way and I was wondering if it is possible to run a script located on the Synology from the Docker container. Totally new to Docker so forgive any stupid questions.

If not, any tips on how to approach this so I can get back to my dayjob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by creating my own image:

```
FROM domoticz/domoticz:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install etherwake wget curl php-cli php-xml php-soap -y
```